# Need to write a Parser in C++

Tags: c++

```
bool check_column_name(Token_stream& ts) {
    Token t = ts.get();
    if(t.kind == '(') {
        while(t.kind != ')') {
            t = ts.get();
                if(t.kind == 'a' || t.kind == '0') {
                    string column_names = "";
                    while(t.kind != ' ' && t.kind != ')') {
                        column_names += t.value;
                        t = ts.get();
                }
                cout << column_names << endl;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I need to Parse this

> (Column_name1 VARCHAR[20], Column_name2 VARCHAR[8], Column_name3
>   INTEGER);

I need to parse that above line to call a Create() function to create a table. After parsing that line I will be able to know what my column names are going to be and how many columns are there in my table and what is the type of each column. For example the first column has name "Column_name1" and its type is "VARCHAR" which would be a string. My code  is able to parse (column_name1 Column_nam2) but that is not what I want. I want to parse the line (Column_name1 VARCHAR[20], Column_name2 VARCHAR[8], Column_name3 INTEGER);.

Comment: No, no help. Write a proper question (including what your program does, what it should do, and why it does not meet your needs) and some help might come along.

Comment: To point out oswald's point, Your example can be parsed with
string line = getLineFromFile();  if (line == "(Column_name1 VARCHAR[20], Column_name2 VARCHAR[8], Column_name3 INTEGER);") return kParsed;`.

What you are really asking for is a parser for a particular grammar, not a parser for an example string

Comment: May I recommend looking up common languages used to describe grammars, such as BNF ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form ).  Use such a language to describe the grammar you want, and then we will be in a much better position to help you build a parser to do what you eed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this the *proper* way is a complex subject. It involves familiarity with grammars, lexers, parsers, and so on.

The most known book on the subject is the "[Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design)".

I've successfully used [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) with C++ in the past for this.

Comment: Another tool that works well is boost::spirit, but it's in the same class as ANTLR: complicated subjects